List of all sequences with certain properties
I am trying to relearn Mathematica after a gap of around 30 years. I want a list of all sequences of non-negative integers with certain properties. Each sequence has the same length len and the sum of the entries in each sequence gives the same total tot. Preferably, the sequences should be in lexicographically decreasing order. I tried to program a recursive approach, but got error messages from functions like Join "arguments must have the same Heads". Any suggestions?

Join takes 2 lists.  To add an element to a list, use Append

Another possibility:
 FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1, 1, 1}, 10] // Reverse

Short[%, 10]

(* {
  {10,0,0,0},{9,1,0,0},{9,0,1,0},{9,0,0,1},{8,2,0,0},{8,1,1,0},  
  {8,1,0,1},{8,0,2,0},{8,0,1,1},{8,0,0,2},{7,3,0,0},{7,2,1,0},  
  {7,2,0,1},{7,1,2,0},{7,1,1,1},{7,1,0,2},{7,0,3,0},{7,0,2,1},
  {7,0,1,2},{7,0,0,3},{6,4,0,0},{6,3,1,0},{6,3,0,1},{6,2,2,0},
  {6,2,1,1},{6,2,0,2},{6,1,3,0},{6,1,2,1},{6,1,1,2},{6,1,0,3},
  {6,0,4,0},{6,0,3,1},{6,0,2,2},{6,0,1,3},{6,0,0,4},{5,5,0,0},
  {5,4,1,0},{5,4,0,1},{5,3,2,0},{5,3,1,1},{5,3,0,2},{5,2,3,0}, 
  {5,2,2,1},{5,2,1,2},{5,2,0,3},{5,1,4,0},{5,1,3,1},{5,1,2,2}, 
  {5,1,1,3},{5,1,0,4},{5,0,5,0},
  <<184>>,
  {0,5,5,0},{0,5,4,1},{0,5,3,2},{0,5,2,3},{0,5,1,4},{0,5,0,5},
  {0,4,6,0},{0,4,5,1},{0,4,4,2},{0,4,3,3},{0,4,2,4},{0,4,1,5},
  {0,4,0,6},{0,3,7,0},{0,3,6,1},{0,3,5,2},{0,3,4,3},{0,3,3,4},   
  {0,3,2,5},{0,3,1,6},{0,3,0,7},{0,2,8,0},{0,2,7,1},{0,2,6,2},
  {0,2,5,3},{0,2,4,4},{0,2,3,5},{0,2,2,6},{0,2,1,7},{0,2,0,8},
  {0,1,9,0},{0,1,8,1},{0,1,7,2},{0,1,6,3},{0,1,5,4},{0,1,4,5},
  {0,1,3,6},{0,1,2,7},{0,1,1,8},{0,1,0,9},{0,0,10,0},{0,0,9,1},
  {0,0,8,2},{0,0,7,3},{0,0,6,4},{0,0,5,5},{0,0,4,6},{0,0,3,7},
  {0,0,2,8},{0,0,1,9},{0,0,0,10}
 } *)


(The OP requires  " 'lexicographically descending', {10,0,0,0}, {9,1,0,0}, {9,0,1,0}, {9,0,0,1}. {8,2,0,0}, etc")

The answers miss sequences like {0,10,0,0,0}

The order I need for my application is "lexicographically descending",
{10,0,0,0}, {9,1,0,0}, {9,0,1,0}, {9,0,0,1}. {8,2,0,0, etc
I had been planning to sort lexicographically after the steps given above. It would be neat if one could give one command that does the whole task.

Elegant solution. Could you write it as an answer that I could "accept"?

Here is a quick and dirty solution, assuming the order matters:
d = Range[10];
n = 4;
sum = 10;
Select[Tuples[d, n], Total[#] == sum &]


If the order does not matter, you may use: IntegerPartitions:
IntegerPartitions[sum, {n}]


